# CS0234 for Referenced Local Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, compiler-errors

I am receiving the

CS0234: The type or namespace name '...' does not exist in the namespace '...' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I notice when I click on "Show Detailed Compiler Output" that the project nor its binary output is referenced in the csc build command.  It was working fine before but after I make a few changes in code, my app started to break.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

It's also worth noting I'm using ASP.NET MVC 2.

Comment: What happens if you remove and re-add the project-reference?

Comment: No go, tried doing that as well as adding a reference to the actual binary output for both debug and release targets.

Comment: Maybe you can explain what changes you have made to your code after this was working.

Comment: Are you sure the assembly you are referencing to contains the namespace that you need? Also, check for the accessibility (private/internal) etc for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ends up ASP.NET is not so good at resolving references. I ended up adding my assembly to the  web.config section and all was good.

Comment: What I add in web.config if my App_GlobalResources stay in the same web project?

Answer (score 0):

Is this a compile time error? I had a similiar error when I made somechanges to my view. If you did any changes in your view and having this kind of issue - let me know, I`ll write how to fix that.